# Inheritance tree: should undirected graph be subclass of directed graph?

Tags: oop, inheritance

I am implementing a simple graph library for practice.
I have created a base class Graph , from which I have derived DirectedGraph.
I was wondering if I should derive UnDirectedGraph class from DirectedGraph or should I derive it from Graph class itself. UnDirected graph is a DirectedGraph in which a edge from u to v implies edge from v to u. Please let me know what is the best way to implement Graph Hierarchy.

Also , Graph class has a list of GraphVertex. Should the GraphVertex Class hold the data for edges going from that vertex or should the graph class hold all the data for all the edges.

Comment: By name, I wouldn't think UndirectedGraph could inherit from DirectedGraph.

Comment: Please mark my answer if it was sufficient, or let me know if you have any questions that I can help for your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, ideally you should structure your inheritance in a way that it would make sense in real world application. Undirected and directed graphs are both Graphs, so your best bet is inheriting from there.

your Graph class could include -> (C++)

```
vector<Node*> nodes;
```

whereas your Directed graph could hold the edges itself.

Also, I have implemented this, my personal and *humble* suggestion is to store everything as a

```
dictionary<int, dictionary<int, int>>
```

(C++ dictionary is unordered_map).

This dictionary is a list of pairs of nodes to a pair of the node its connected to with a weight.

That is for a weighted graph.

Hopefully this is a good answer, doesn't include much code but might set you on the right track.